# i18n pluralization with ruby on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pluralize

```
irb(main):023:0> article.impressions_count
=> 26
```

In the article show view I have:

```
<%= t(".impressions", :impressions => @article.impressions_count) %>
```

I would like pluralize with something like this on my `es.yml` file:

```
impressions:
 one: "%{impressions} visualización"
 other: "%{impressions} visualizaciones"
```

However I get:

```
{:one=>"%{impressions} visualización", :other=>"%{impressions} visualizaciones"}
```

How can I pluralize the article impressions_count attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead :impressions, pass :count as a key

```
<%= t(".impressions", count: @article.impressions_count) %>

one: "%{count} visualización"
other: "%{count} visualizaciones"
```

Comment: This code does works if reload page 1 or more times. Immediately after creating the object I get the same result: `{:one=>"%{count} visualización", :other=>"%{count} visualizaciones"}` Thanks!

Comment: do you use ajax or something alike?

Comment: No. I use redirect_to after of create the object :). Thanks!. I have added a `unless` condition in `@article.impressions_count` is nil don't show `@article.impressions_count` to remove the error the first time.